# 3d cube not working in IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have created a 3d cube and have it working in both Chrome and FF, but cannot get it to work in IE. I know that IE does not support `preserve-3d` and have looked into the work around. The problem is, I don't really have a `transform` on my parent element, just a `transition` with transform inside it. I have tried adding the `transition: transform 1s` to all the children, but it didn't seem to change anything. Any help getting this to work properly in all browsers would be greatly appreciated!! Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAVF7/)

HTML:

```
<div id="options">
<ul id="nav">
  <li id="front" class="show-front">Show 1</li>
  <li id="back" class="show-back">Show 2</li>
  <li id="right" class="show-right">Show 3</li>
  <li id="left" class="show-left">Show 4</li>
  <li id="top" class="show-top">Show 5</li>
  <li id="bottom" class="show-bottom">Show 6</li>
<ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div id="cube" class="show-front">
  <div class="side front">1</div>
  <div class="side back">2</div>
  <div class="side right">3</div>
  <div class="side left">4</div>
  <div class="side top">5</div>
  <div class="side bottom">6</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
width:400px;
height:400px;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto 40px;
-webkit-perspective:1000px;
-moz-perspective:1000px;
-ms-perspective:1000px;
-o-perspective:1000px;
perspective:1000px;
}

.container #cube {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 1s;
    -ms-transition:-ms-transform 1s;
    -o-transition:-o-transform 1s;
    transition:transform 1s
}

.container #cube .side {
background:rgba(204,204,204,.9);
margin:0;
display:block;
position:absolute;
width:396px;
height:396px;
border:2px solid rgba(147,184,189,.8);
line-height:196px;
font-size:120px;
font-weight:700;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow:0 5px 20px rgba(105,108,109,.3),0 0 8px 5px rgba(208,223,226,.4) inset;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
-o-backface-visibility:hidden;
backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.container #cube .front {
-webkit-transform:translateZ(200px);
-moz-transform:translateZ(200px);
-ms-transform:translateZ(200px);
-o-transform:translateZ(200px);
transform:translateZ(200px);
}

.container #cube .back {
-webkit-transform:rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(200px);
-moz-transform:rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(200px);
-ms-transform:rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(200px);
-o-transform:rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(200px);
transform:rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.container #cube .right {
-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
-moz-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
-ms-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
-o-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.container #cube .left {
-webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
-moz-transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
-ms-transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
-o-transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.container #cube .top {
-webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
-moz-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
-ms-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
-o-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.container #cube .bottom {
-webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
-moz-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
-ms-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
-o-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(200px);
}

.container #cube.show-front {
-webkit-transform:translateZ(-200px);
-moz-transform:translateZ(-200px);
-ms-transform:translateZ(-200px);
-o-transform:translateZ(-200px);
transform:translateZ(-200px);
}

.container #cube.show-back {
-webkit-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-180deg);
-moz-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-180deg);
-ms-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-180deg);
-o-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-180deg);
transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-180deg);
}

.container #cube.show-right {
-webkit-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-90deg);
-moz-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-90deg);
-ms-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-90deg);
-o-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-90deg);
transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.container #cube.show-left {
-webkit-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(90deg);
-moz-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(90deg);
-ms-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(90deg);
-o-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(90deg);
transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateY(90deg);
}

.container #cube.show-top {
-webkit-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-90deg);
-moz-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-90deg);
-ms-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-90deg);
-o-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-90deg);
transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(-90deg);
}

.container #cube.show-bottom {
-webkit-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(90deg);
-moz-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(90deg);
-ms-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(90deg);
-o-transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(90deg);
transform:translateZ(-200px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

Comment: did you got any solution? this link might be useful for you. http://codepen.io/dehash/pen/LwIyE

Answer (score 0):

In IE you cannot apply a transform property to the parent (#cube) and expect the children to behave accordingly. You will need to apply an appropriate transform to each child, individually.